# Toggle a field visibility inside a dynamic rows ui-component

Tags: uicomponent, magento2.4, toggle

I have a dynamic field ui-component inside an admin form that contains a few columns.
And I also have a toggle field outside the dynamic rows.
I want to show/hide a column inside the dynamic fields based on the state of the toggle.
I was able to make the column hide but the header still remains.

Here is my code

My toggle definition

```
    <field name="aggregate" formElement="checkbox">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">entity</item>
                <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Aggregate</label>
            <dataScope>aggregate</dataScope>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <checkbox>
                <settings>
                    <valueMap>
                        <map name="false" xsi:type="number">0</map>
                        <map name="true" xsi:type="number">1</map>
                    </valueMap>
                    <prefer>toggle</prefer>
                </settings>
            </checkbox>
        </formElements>
    </field>
```

here is my dynamic rows component. the component contains more fields, but I added only the one in question.

```
    <dynamicRows name="fields_serialized">
        <settings>
            <addButtonLabel translate="true">Add Row</addButtonLabel>
            <additionalClasses>
                <class name="admin__field-wide">true</class>
            </additionalClasses>
            <componentType>dynamicRows</componentType>
            <dndConfig>
                <param name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</param>
            </dndConfig>
        </settings>
        <container name="record">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true" />
                    <item name="isTemplate" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="is_collection" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="showFallbackReset" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <field name="aggregate" formElement="select" component="Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">fields_serialized</item>
                        <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="chipsEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <settings>
                    <elementTmpl>ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</elementTmpl>
                    <dataType>text</dataType>
                    <label translate="true">Aggregation</label>
                    <dataScope>aggregate</dataScope>
                    <validation>
                        <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                    </validation>
                    <componentType>field</componentType>
                    <imports>
                        <link name="visible">[path.to.toogle.component.here].aggregate:checked</link> 
                    </imports>
                </settings>
                <formElements>
                    <select>
                        <settings>
                            <options class="SourceModelClassHere"/>
                        </settings>
                    </select>
                </formElements>
            </field>
        </container>
    </dynamicRows>
```

the `imports` part in the record works nicely to show/hide the column inside the rows but it leaves the header.

```
<imports>
    <link name="visible">[path.to.toogle.component.here].aggregate:checked</link> 
</imports>
```

When changing the state of the main toggle I get something like this:

[image: toggle off]

Initially it looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find a way to do it without creating new component. So I created a new component:

```
define(
    ['Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/dynamic-rows', 'ko'],
    function (DynamicRows, ko) {
        return DynamicRows.extend({
            initObservable: function () {
                var self = this;
                this.aggregate = ko.observable(false);
                this._super();
                this.aggregate.subscribe(function (value) {
                    self.setAggregate(value);
                });
                return this;
            },
            setAggregate: function (value) {
                var labels = this.labels();
                labels.map(function (label) {
                    if (label.name === 'aggregate') {
                        label.visible(value);
                    }
                });
            },
            initHeader: function () {
                this._super();
                this.setAggregate(this.aggregate());
            }
        });
    }
);
```

and declared my dynamic rows as an instance of the component above and added an import link to it

```
<dynamicRows name="fields_serialized" component="[Namespace]_[Module]/js/dynamic-rows">
    ....
    <settings>
        <imports>
            <link name="aggregate">path.to.toogle.field.aggregate:checked</link>
        </imports>
    </settings>
</dynamicRows>
```

I know that the check "if (label.name === 'aggregate') {" is not that clean, and does not make the component very reusable, but it can be improved by adding the columns that should be hidden via the xml config.